# Implementing a relational data model: what are the constraints for this table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm trying to come up with a relational model and database implementation, but keep running into this problem.  But I don't even know what to call it!  Suggestions for improving the title would be appreciated.

I've tried to boil the problem down to its basics.

---

Simplified example:

Here's the MySQLWorkbench diagram:

[image: MySQLWorkbench data model]

---

As you can see, **the problems are all with the `Atom` table**.

**Outline of desired goal:**

- I need to store data for specific atoms of proteins
- I may have data for some of the atoms, or none of the atoms
- I don't want to be able to insert junk data -- I'd like for the database constraints to prevent this

What I'm not sure about:

- whether there should be an `Atom` table -- it seems like a join between `Atom_ref` and `Residue` would generate all the atoms of the protein -- but I also need to store data about the atoms

**Outline of problem:**

- each atom needs a residue, and an atom_ref
- but since the residue is associated with a residue_ref, the atom_ref can only be one of the associated (with the residue_ref) atom_ref's
- don't know how to match the residue_ref of the Residue with the residue_ref of the atom_ref

What I've tried so far:

- add the pk of `Atom_ref` to the pk of `Atom` -- but then the residue_ref might not match that of `Residue`
- change `Residue.rr_name` to part of the pk -- violates domain semantics

---

I know this is a poor explanation of the problem, I'm trying to figure out how to explain it more clearly!  Suggestions for improvement are more than welcome!

Comment: the main problem here is being able to explain in simple sentences this problem-domain. Really, that's all to it. So start like: `Residue is..`; `Protein contains ...`; `Residue type is ..`. And so on. For example your sentence: *...Each atom needs a residue ... * Is this correct? Do atoms need a residue?

Comment: @DamirSudarevic -- you are right, I struggled with trying to explain this both fully and accurately, and I believe I've failed.  Any suggestions for improving the question would be appreciated.

Comment: @MattFenwick: Try to explain in simple terms your model (forget about `_ref` or anything else that may obscure others). How would you explain this to a kid? A protein can have many residues and a residue belongs to one protein. Right? A residue can have many atoms and an atom belongs to one residue. Right? (That's what the 3 tables: Protein, Residue, Atom describe). What else is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then what you're after is an inclusion dependency between (a) the join of Atom and Residue, and (b) Atom_ref.  (i.e. all atomnames in Atom, combined with the rr_name defined for it in residue, must be declared as being valid combinations, i.e. must appear in Atomref).

The way to do it using merely RI/FK, is to include rr_name in Atom, redundantly.  Extend the FK from Atom to Residue to all three columns.  This will guarantee you that the rr_names recorded in Atom remain consistent with the information in Residue.  But since you have now introduced rr_name in Atom, you now have the means to ensure (through an FK atomname+rrname from Atom to Atom_ref) that whatever is recorded in Atom, is also consistent with the atomnames which have been declared (In atomref) to exist for the residueref involved.

Note that this "solution" makes updating your database harder (more redundancy to maintain, giving rise to more potential for violations), because you have just lowered the NF level of your design.

The other way to do it is to leave your design as is, and enforce the constraint through appropriate triggers on every involved table where an update could cause a violation of your business rule.  That would be, deletes and updates on Atom_ref (i.e. anything that causes the disappearing of a valid combination that effectively exists somewhere), updates (of rr_name) on Residue, and inserts and updates on Atom (i.e. anything that might cause the appearance of some combination that might not be valid).

Comment: Another possible approach: revoke write permissions from the base tables and provide stored procs to implement CRUD operations while maintaining integrity. This code can target updates to tables in the required order; the equivalent code in triggers has to consder updates in all directions (if you see what I mean) which I find harder to write.

Comment: Correct.  I was only thinking of enforcing the constraint.  In the design with the redundant rr_name, he'd probably need to make his FK cascade any update, and if he uses triggers, he'd probably want to write them such that they achieve the same effect as the cascade update of the first scenario (instead of bluntly rejecting the update).  However, I counted 5 triggers to implement.  Doesn't your SPROC approach give you 3 tables * 3 update types = 9 modules to implement (and test and deploy and maintain and ...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Within a protein, are the residue names unique?  I.E., could you create a unique constraint on `Residue (p_id, rr_name)`?

If so, then in `Atom` you could replace `r_index` with `rr_name`; create an FK on `(p_id,rr_name)` to `Residue`; and create an FK on `(rr_name, atom_name)` to `Atom_ref`.

**Edit**:  Yeah, I figured it probably wouldn't be that simple.  I think your second bullet point is sort of the right direction -- but don't change the PK of `Residue`, just create a new unique constraint on all three columns.  The two constraints may even be able to share one index.  Then you can add `rr_name` to `Atom`, and give it a three-column FK to `Residue` and a two-column FK to `Atom_ref`.

Comment: No, unfortunately; there are lots of the same `rr_name` in each protein.

Comment: So I can include a non-PK column as part of a foreign key in a different table?

Comment: I don't know about MySQL, but in Oracle a foreign key can reference a PK or a unique constraint

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between atom and atom_ref? Looking at your table structure, it appears as if the Residue_ref and Atom_ref are to express the many-to-many relationships between Atoms and Residues. (Sorry, I never took biochem, so I may be missing something important).

Is there data specific to an Atom in context of a specific Residue? If the answer is no, I would reduce the Residue_ref and Atom_ref tables down to a single table: atoms_residues that looks like this:

```
atoms_residue(r_index, atom_index)
```

This would ensure that a specific atom from the atom table appears in relation to the residue table.

If there IS context information for the atom-residue pairing, I would still create the above table and consider adding the context information as columns to that table.

The key is encapsulation. Atom-specific data should be in the atom table. Residue-specific data should be in the Residue table. A join table expresses the many-many relationship between the two and can optionally also contain any information unique to that relationship.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't think this will work.  I'm pretty confident about all the tables except for `Atom`.

Comment: What are the purpose of the two _ref tables? The only two columns you provide are identity specific.

Comment: Trying to keep it simple (maybe failing).  Basically, the ref tables are unchanging -- they lay out all of the residue types, and the atoms contained in each.  Then a protein consists of 100's of residues (each of which has a type, which dictates the atoms in it) in a linear sequence.